# using tf.float16 instead of tf.float32 or 64 increase memory right?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, floating-point, out-of-memory

If my keras model compile failed due to out of memory. does changing the data set from float32 to float16 might fix the problem? if not, what is the advantage of decreasing float32 to float16?

Thanks

Comment: All ops are faster with float16 comparing to float32

Comment: so its a matter of faster convergere instead of saving memory? or both?

Comment: I didn't see saving memory but I am not sure